# Usage of というのに in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I think I understand the meaning of the following passage, but I'm non really sure about the usage of というのに in this case. Can you help me?

環境に影響の大きい自家用車での来場を減らす努力をしないというのに矛盾を感じるんです。

Comment: Can you elaborate what you understand from the passage and what you think というのに might be?

Comment: Actually when I first read the sentece I translated without includinf というのに, so it was something like : I feel the contradiction of not putting more effort in diminishing the big cars of the attendees that have an impact on the environment. How does it sound? I know that literally is "the car that will come" but, in my opinion, it sounded a little strange :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I still have a doubt. Do you mean that in this case の is used in place of もの？ moreover, it means that in a sentence without a name the patter would be only のに？ as instance, "現代ほど自分の主体性、価値観を築き上げるのにむずかしい時代はないのだろう。"

Answer (score 3):

というのに is often used as a [set phrase that works like a conjunction](http://www.romajidesu.com/dictionary/meaning-of-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AB.html) ("although ～"), but this というのに is not idiomatic.

- という explains the following noun, see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/52003/5010).
- の is a nominalizer (which is technically a formal noun).
- に is a case particle, "to", "in", "against", etc. "XにYを感じる" means "I feel Y in/for X."

So the sentence means the same thing as 努力をしない(という)ことに矛盾を感じる.

> I feel it contradictory that they do not make efforts to reduce the use of ...