# What is a good translation for 不平不満を持ちながもらしょうがなく乗り切ることを言います。?

Tags: translation

I came across a website in Japanese that explains the difference between 我慢 and 耐える. The link is https://ameblo.jp/naka-tatsuya/entry-11896324259.html

The full sentence is as follows:

> 我慢というのはその時、その場しのぎで、不平不満を持ちながもらしょうがなく乗り切ることを言います。

I was able to translate the first part, which goes something like, “Saying 我慢 is a temporary or stopgap measure, and...”

I think the second part goes something like, “They are saying that they will survive without having complaints and grumbling.”

I don't know, guys. The second part has me really stumped. I would really appreciate if you could help me understand the proper way to translate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 我慢というのはその時、その場しのぎで、不平不満を持ちながらも、しょうがなく乗り切ることを言います。
>   (The idea of) *Gaman* is taking stopgap measures and getting away, not knowing what else to do, even though you have complaints.

ながもら should be a typo for [ながらも](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8C%E3%82%89%E3%82%82-nagara-mo/), a stiff way of saying "even though". 乗り切る is "to go through (a difficult part)", "to get away (from an undesirable situation)", etc. しょうがなく is "having no other choice", "as a last resort", etc. And let's not overuse "say" to translate という, see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/52003/5010).

---

Anyway, that article is not something you can trust as a language learner. The article is saying 耐える is a more positive word used with a future prospect, but I don't agree with this explanation. In addition, 耐える has etymologically nothing to do with 多得る; it's just his own wordplay.

The fundamental difference between 耐える and 我慢する is in their usages.

耐える is an intransitive verb used in the form of ～に耐える, and its used with some *unwanted* stress, situation, attack, desire, etc. When the target is a clearly *external* one, 耐える is the only choice. The subject of 耐える can be an inanimate object, too.

我慢する is a transitive verb, and it can be used with something you want to do, especially your own desire.

Use 耐える for external things:

> - 我々は敵の攻撃に耐えた。 (敵の攻撃 is external and undesirable)
> - 困難に耐えた。 ("hard situation" is something clearly external to you)
> - この防具はライフルの弾に耐えられる。 (防具 is inanimate)

Use 我慢する for things you want to do/use:

> - 食事を我慢する, 食べたいのを我慢する
> - 贅沢を我慢する
> - シャワーを我慢する, トイレを我慢する

Both can be used when the target is an unwanted internal feeling/desire:

> - 眠気に耐える = 眠気を我慢する
> - 空腹に耐える = 空腹を我慢する
> - 痛みに耐える = 痛みを我慢する

When two are interchangeable, I feel 耐える sounds a little stiffer and more formal.

Comment: Thank you so much! So there was a typo in the sentence! I guess that proves that Japanese sentences can contain typos. I think you went above and beyond the call of duty to answe this question!