# という店もあります meaning in that sentence?

Tags: meaning

I don't get the meaning of という店もあります in that sentence. I understand: "This month sales were 10 times higher than the sales from April last year", then I have no clue for the end of the sentence.

> 今月の売り上げが去年の４月の１０倍になったという店もあります

My guess is:

> "This month sales were 10 times higher than the sales from April last year for one of the shop".

By the way, this is the complete sentence:

> 大阪ではタピオカを入れた飲み物を売る店がたくさんできていて、今月の売り上げが去年の４月の１０倍になったという店もあります。

Can you guys help me please?

Comment: I know that you said that you have not clue for the end, but can you give us your best guess? It will help us give you a more useful answer.

Comment: Sure! My guess is: "This month sales were 10 times higher than the sales from April last year for one of the shop". 
By the way, this is the complete sentence: 大阪ではタピオカを入れた飲み物を売る店がたくさんできていて、今月の売り上げが去年の４月の１０倍になったという店もあります。

Comment: も means "too" or an emphatic "even", so it could be talking about more than one store, or emphasizing that there is at least one store that has earned more money. I don't know the full context, but you got it right, imo.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's clearer now!

Answer (score 4):

The main clause of this sentence is simple:

> 店もあります。
>   There are even/also stores.

And there is a long relative clause modifying 店. This という is quotative-と followed by 言う, but is a very common combination used to describe a following noun. See [my previous answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/52003/5010) for examples. In this case, you can use "where" or "in which".

> ～という店もあります。
>   There are even stores where ～.

Therefore:

> 今月の売り上げが去年の4月の10倍になったという店もあります。
>   There are even (tapioca) stores where this month's sales were 10 times higher than the sales from April last year.

Comment: (It could also be “a store” FWIW)

Comment: FWIW, I think this という is a  marker of reportative  evidentiality, which conveys the nuance of, well, "reportedly"