# 「よいことをする」という気負いがない分、自然体でボランティアに関われる人も多いのです。

Tags: meaning

「よいことをする」という気負いがない分、自然体でボランティアに関われる人も多いのです。

Can someone explain the meaning of this?
From what I see:

> 'doing good thing' in other words NOT being enthusiastic, these type of non enthusiastic people are a lot?

Comment: What part of the Japanese do you think corresponds to "in other words"?

Comment: 「よいことをする」という is a relative clause modifying 気負い: ie, describing what kind of 気負い this is.  In these sorts of relative clauses という isn't really directly translatable into English, you could treat B**という**A as meaning "A **that is** a B sort of thing".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- という is not "in other words". Please read [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/52003/5010) and get used to how it works.
- This 気負い means "pressure put on oneself" or "(negative) self-consciousness" rather than "enthusiasm". (The [definitions from jisho.org](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%B0%97%E8%B2%A0%E3%81%84) are admittedly misleading. 気負い refers to "It's *MY* job" kind of eagerness/pressure, not enthusiasm in general.)
- 自然体 is "natural stance", and 自然体で roughly means "like one's regular self".
- 分 is "to the extent" or "the more ～ the more ～".

> 「よいことをする」という気負いがない分、自然体でボランティアに関われる人も多いのです。
>
> There are also many people who are engaged in volunteer activities in a natural manner all the more because they have no self-imposed pressure to "do good things".

Comment: Two things stood in my way of answering this: (1) a good understanding of 気負い.  even my native Japanese dictionaries left me a bit fuzzy.  (2) I've seen constructions like this before with 分 but that also left me scratching my head.   jisho.org's definition just didn't work no matter how I thought about it.  With a better definition of 気負い how to work with 分 probably would have fell into place.