# 「広がる広げる漢字の知識」ってどういう意味ですか

Tags: translation

I believe that it must be some word play here, but what does it really mean? What is 広がる広げる？

Edit: この文は漢字教材で出会いました。特別なコラムみたいなものです。普通の音読みと訓読みなどの学習ではなく、音の濁りや形声文字について紹介しています。

Comment: Where did you come across this? Context is often invaluable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this the title of a book, article, lecture or such? This phrase is not really a wordplay. It's just 広がる漢字の知識 ("expanding knowledge of kanji"; 広がる is intransitive) and 広げる漢字の知識 ("knowledge of kanji *you* expand"; 広げる is transitive) said together. Technically, it's an example of [right-node raising](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17744/5010).

Comment: Thanks naruto sensei. It's from a Japanese kanji learning book. It is a page about special tips and 'did you know' like style of information.

Answer (score 0):

We use "知識を広げる" when I want to say "understand deeply/well".

at first, the knowledge(知識) is a point.

when you learn deeply, its gonna be spread.

and this time there is two words "広げる and 広がる".

by read/watch this book/movie(I guess its title of a book/movie for learning something), spread your knowledge by yourself(広げる＝transitive verb), and, your knowledge is gonna be spread Naturally (intransitive verb).

so, the words 広げる広がる　want to say "you can get really good effect by read/watch it".

we use such expression for advertising slogan only, we seldom use it for daily talk.