# Meaning of しない in sign 飲酒運転しないさせない我が職場

Tags: translation, parsing

I can't understand this sign. Part しない just doesn't make sense to me. If it weren't there I would translate it as "Drunken driving isn't allowed. This region under my duty" (later part I would assume so due to subtitle about police, so this sign is probably is written from the point of view of police-man. But it would be way to aggressive, so I'm probably wrong here too?)

But with しない it turns into "Drunken driving is a must!" which is definetly wrong.

What does しない stand for?

[image]

Comment: A similar set phrase: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60203/7810

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [標語]{ひょうご}. So each phrase is written to match the 5 and 7 mora counts (like 川柳 and 俳句):

> いんしゅうんてん -- 7 mora
> しない、させない -- 7 mora
> わがしょくば -- 5 mora

To rewrite it in a nomal way it'd be like:

> 「飲酒運転をしない。飲酒運転をさせない。わが職場では。」
> 「うちの職場では、飲酒運転をしません。飲酒運転をさせません。」
> "We don't do drunken-driving, don't let others do drunken-driving, in our workplace"

Answer (score 3):

Meaning-wise, it means "Drunk driving in our/your workplace: don't do, don't let someone else do."

The order of the words is slightly unusual so to emphasize 「飲酒運転」(that, for this reason, is written in red), rather than 「我が職場」. In addition, the space between the verbs implies that those are two different actions, which is not unusual in Japanese copywriting - especially in PSA-like advertisements. I have seen some examples in my workplace before (unfortunately, I can't upload them here).