# Shared verb between 2 phrases

Tags: syntax

I came across this おれがあなたをあなたはおれを守る, which most probably means 'I will protect you and you will protect me'. The question that arises is there are from the looks of it, the phrrases (おれあがあんたを) and (あなたはおれを)  connected to each other, finally followed by the verb to end it. I am assuming that the verb is shared between these 2 phrases. So the above sentence means exactly the same as 俺があなたを守ってあなたは俺を守る. Is this correct? Also, can this structure be used in any context? For example, 俺は魚彼は鳥肉が好き。 Also, does this extends to theoretically, any number of phrases?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17743/5010