# noun が、noun が、verb (multiple が in a sentence)

Tags: particle-が

Is it possible to grammatically combine two separate sentences Xがverb。Yがverb。into just one sentence Xが、Yが、verb。? For example,

> 料理ができる。掃除ができる。→ 料理が、掃除が、できる。

My original motivation is to understand the role of が in the more complex sentence:

> ただ喜びと悲しみのあいだにある多くの事象**が**、その互いの位置関係みたいなもの**が**、まだうまく見きわめられなかっただけだ。(村上 春樹. 一人称単数 (Japanese Edition) (Kindle Locations 23-25)

I found many questions regarding multiple use of the が particle in a sentence but to the best of my knowledge they concern the case in which one of the が is on a relative clause which I think it is not the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have suggested is possible. Murakami's sentence is an example of right-node raising explained here:

- [Use of first が in 町の後ろに山が、前に海があって、](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17743/5010)

But usually you should not do this in a simple sentence like 「料理が、掃除ができる」. This sounds unnecessarily literary or even theatrical to me. This might be fine in lyrics or as a catchphrase of a robot, but in most cases you should be saying 料理や掃除ができる or 料理と掃除ができる instead.

Comment: もちろん、the simple sentences were meant only to make the question easy to read. Many thanks!