# 会社の制裁についてです。採用契約に書いてあるものですが、意味がわかりません。

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 1回の額が平均賃金の1日分の半額、総額が一賃金支払期における賃金総額の10分の1以内で減給する。

ここの「一回の額」と「総額」ってどういう意味ですか

Answer (score 2):

- **1回の額**: 1回の減給額 = per-event amount (of pay cut)
- **総額**: 減給の総額 = total (or accumulated/cumulative) amount (of pay cut)

This is a sentence that says the following two things at the same time ([right-node raising](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17744/5010)):

- 1回の額が平均賃金の1日分の半額以内で減給する。
- 総額が一賃金支払期における賃金総額の10分の1以内で減給する。

If you do something wrong just once, a wage of up to 0.5 days will be deducted. Even if you do something wrong many times, the cumulative amount of penalty will not exceed (0.1 × 一賃金支払期における賃金総額) yen.

一賃金支払期における賃金総額 basically refers to your monthly salary (if you are paid monthly).

Comment: I don't understand what 10分の1 means here.

Comment: @JimmyYang It's 'one tenth', or 1/10, or 10% (of a month's salary).

Comment: Thanks, one more thing: If 1回の額 and 総額 both refer to pay cut, then 減給する actually means "to increase (pay cut)"?

Comment: @JimmyYang 減給する is just "to cut salary". 額 refers to the "amount" (of money). Literally, 1万円以内で減給する = "to cut salary up to 10,000 yen", 1回の額が1万円以内で減給する = "to cut salary with a per-event amount being up to 10,000 yen".

Comment: Ah, that means I should understand the sentence like this way「(1回の額が1万円以内で)減給する」, 1回の額 is not a subject for 減給する, and it modifies 1万円以内. Is that right?

Comment: @JimmyYang Yes, exactly.

Comment: so, if I do something wrong many times, I'll get 9000円 if the salary is 10000円？

Comment: @kuroitora Theoretically yes, but in practice, 減給 is not a common penalty at least in Japan. You may get fired before getting 10% of your salary deducted.