# と-particle as "and" vs. と-particle as "with"

Tags: particle-と

1. **と as "and":** This follows the Noun＋と＋Noun(と) pattern:

> 犬**と**猫がいる
>
> There is a dog *and* a cat.

2. **と as "with":**

> 友達**と**遊ぶ。
>
> Play *with* friend.

3. **Combining both senses at once:** Here the first と is being used in the "and" sense, while the second is being used in the "with" sense:

> 父**と**母**と**公園に行きます。
>
> I'm going to the park *with* my father *and* mother.

**Question:** Do native Japanese view these two uses of と as one, singular concept? Or do they view them as two seperate things that just happen to both use "と"?

I ask because if I squint my eyes I can kind of see the "and" usage of と being subsumed by the "with" usage:

> 犬と猫がいる
>
> => There is a dog *with* a cat.

> 父と母と公園に行きます。
>
> => I'm going to the park *with* my father, *with* my mother.

As far as I can tell, these convey basically the same meaning as the original translations. So I'm wondering if the fact that English speakers parse と as either "and" or "with" is some quirk of our language, and not the way actual Japanese people see it?

Comment: I don't really know how native speakers view this question, but arguably I think considering these to be two separate ideas is more a quirk of English than anything inherent in the concepts themselves.  If you consider と to mean something along the lines of "along with", for example, then the same translation works pretty well in all of these cases.  However, it is also true that と can function grammatically in two different ways (noun-noun connector vs verbal particle), so there could arguably be some level of conceptual distinction between those two uses, I dunno.

Answer (score 2):

This question is hard to answer logically. A native speaker of a language doesn't try to analyze the role of a function word like you do. Have you ever wondered [how many roles the English preposition *with* has](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/with/) from the perspective of a foreigner? Some of them may seem quite similar to someone, but other people may not agree with them.

That said, putting aside uncommon literary sentences and complicated sentences like [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17743/5010), one verb cannot take the same particle twice for the same purpose (e.g., パンをステーキを食べる and 彼に彼女に会う are incorrect). I suppose many untrained native Japanese speakers would intuitively feel those two と's are at least slightly different.

Comment: Fascinating RE the "one verb cannot take the same particle twice for the same purpose" rule. I had never noticed it.

Comment: I think that does still really depend a lot on the particle involved, though.  For example, も is arguably commonly used repeatedly for the same purpose in many sentences.  は can also be used repeatedly in many situations...