# I cannot understand 才能には副作用

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics

This line is from 宇多田ヒカル's song *君に夢中*, but this simple sentence is hardly understandable to, me even associating it with context, because the sentence lacks essential parts that usually make up a complete sentence. You can only guess its meaning by に.
I don't know what に means here. I guess maybe there are three possible answers:

1. に is indicating location, so the sentence means there is a side effect in talent
2. に is indicating 比較・割合の基準や、比較の対象, so the sentence means something's side effect is harmful to talent
3. に is indicating the subject, so it means talent is very side effect

Can anyone help me understand it?

> 完璧に見えるあの人も疲れて帰るよ
> **才能には副作用**
> 栄光には影が付き纏う
> オートロックのドアが閉まる
> 靴と鎧を脱ぎ捨てる
> ここから先はプライベート

Comment: This is a typical example of [right-node raising](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17744/5010). The common part, `が付き纏う`, has been pulled out.

Answer (score 3):

This part

> 才能には副作用
>
> 栄光には影が付き纏う

is a contracted form of 才能には副作用が付き纏い、栄光には影が付き纏う, where the first が付き纏い is omitted to avoid a repetition. Literally *side effect is attached to talent and shadow to glory* (in English, the omission happens in the opposite way).

So the に is the most basic *to* (e.g 付加 #8 [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%AB/#je-56984)).