# double が in a sentence

Tags: particle-が

早く彼を助けに行かないと。　そう思うのに、脚が動かない。

視界を塗りこめる赤が、　嗅覚が麻痺しそうな血の臭いが怖くて。

What exactly the double が here signifies?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of first が in 町の後ろに山が、前に海があって、](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17743/use-of-first-%e3%81%8c-in-%e7%94%ba%e3%81%ae%e5%be%8c%e3%82%8d%e3%81%ab%e5%b1%b1%e3%81%8c-%e5%89%8d%e3%81%ab%e6%b5%b7%e3%81%8c%e3%81%82%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6)

Answer (score 1):

You already know the usage of が　right? It’s showing an array of these reasons in a row. Like

A is, and B is scary.